# Proof of Bolzano-Weierstrass in $\mathbb{R}^k$

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

I can't seem to follow the logic behind the proof of BWT when generalized to $\mathbb{R}^k$. The one I'm trying to understand is as follows

Let $\{x^{(n)}\}$ be a bounded sequence in $\mathbb{R}^k$, then we consider the sequence of first coordinates of each of the sequence elements. I think I understand this because the sequence will be
$$
\{x^{(n)}\} = \left(x^{(1)},x^{(2)},...\right)
$$
But each of the components $x^{(n)}$ is a $k$-tuple. So
$$
x^{(n)} = \left(x_1^{(n)},x_2^{(n)},...,x_k^{(n)}\right)
$$
So this means the sequence of first elements is going to just be $\{x_1^{(n)}\} = (x_1^{(1)},x_1^{(2)},...)$. I understand that this is just a real valued sequence and it's bounded so by BWT for $\mathbb{R}$ it has a convergent sub-sequence. Here's where I lose understanding

Let $\{x^{(n_k)}\}$ be the corresponding sub-sequence of $\{x^{(n)}\}$,then the sequence $\{x_2^{(n_k)}\}$ consisting of second components of $\{x^{(n_k)}\}$ is again a bounded sequence of real numbers.

What do we mean by letting $\{x^{(n_k)}\}$ be the corresponding sub-sequence of $\{x^{(n)}\}$? How can we construct a sequence consisting of second components of $\{x_1^{(n)}\}$ if it's just a real valued sequence so only has one second coordinate?

Thanks in advance for any clarifications!

Comment: You know that $\left(x^{(n)}_1 \right)_n$ has a convergent subsequence. The called this subsequence $\left(x^{(n_k)}_1\right)_k.$

Comment: It means choosing the same $n_k$ for your vector subsequence. That is, you chose $n_k$ for a subsequence of $(x^(n)_1$, then you use the same $n_k$ for the vector subsequance.

Comment: Ok but then how could we construct $(x_2^{(n_k)})$? Is it the sequence of second components of the original $(x^{(n)})$ or is it from $(x^{(n_k)})$? @WilliamM.

Comment: It is a new subsequence, $x^{n_{k_m}}_2$

Comment: Of which original sequence? Sorry it's not clicking @yonatan

Comment: Let me describe the process by example. You have a sequence $(x^1_1,x^1_2,x^1_3),(x^2_1,x^2_2,x^2_3),(x^3_1,x^3_2,x^3_3)...$. You then choose a subsequence such that the first component converges, like $(x^1_1,x^1_2,x^1_3), (x^3_1,x^3_2,x^3_3)...$. Then you choose a subsequence such that the second component converges, like $(x^1_1,x^1_2,x^1_3), (x^4_1,x^4_2,x^4_3)...$. Then you do the same for the third component. You are left with a sequence. Hope this helps.

Comment: @AndreyYanyuk you take subsequence of subsequence. In fact, the subindex notation makes this quite ugly. Better to say there exists increasing $\varphi_1$ such that $x^{(\varphi_1(n))}_1$ converges and then a further subsequence of this for which the second coordinate converges would be $x^{(\varphi_2 \circ \varphi_1(n))}_2;$ etc. At the end, you should construct $x^{(\varphi_k \circ \cdots \circ \varphi_1(n))}$ and since this is a subsequence of each subsequence contructed, all coordinates will converge.

Comment: Ok I think I get it thanks! @WilliamM

Comment: The example helps thank you!@yonatan

Comment: The real secret here is that nobody wants to write out in precise notation what a subsequence of a subsequence of a subsequence is.  Every textbook is going to avoid that.   Even Wiki: "the general case  ... can be reduced to the case of $\mathbb {R} ^{1}$  as follows: ... the sequence of first coordinates is a bounded real sequence, hence it has a convergent subsequence. One can extract a sub-subsequence on which the second coordinates converge, and so on, ... in the end we have passed from the original sequence to a subsequence ... which is still a subsequence of the original sequence."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another, perhaps more clear, way to prove Bolzano-Weierstrass on $\mathbb{R}^n$ using Bolzano-Weierstrass on $\mathbb{R}$ would be to instead use induction on $n$. I'll add a lot of spacing so that it is easy to see which sequence we are dealing with, as this can be a subtlety hidden in the indices.

So if $n=1$ then we just have Bolzano-Weierstrass on $\mathbb{R}$, so this takes care of the base case.

Now suppose Bolzano-Weierstrass holds in $\mathbb{R}^k$ for some $k\in\mathbb{Z}^+$. Then let

$$\left\{\left(x_1^{(m)},\dots,x_{k+1}^{(m)}\right)\right\}_{m\in\mathbb{N}}$$

be a bounded sequence in $\mathbb{R}^{k+1}$. Then

$$\left\{\left(x_1^{(m)},\dots,x_{k}^{(m)}\right)\right\}_{m\in\mathbb{N}}$$

is a bounded subsequence in $\mathbb{R}^k$, so by the induction hypothesis it has a convergent subsequence

$$\left\{\left(x_1^{(m_s)},\dots,x_{k}^{(m_s)}\right)\right\}_{s\in\mathbb{N}}.$$

Furthermore, consider the subsequence $\left\{x_{k+1}^{(m_s)}\right\}_{s\in\mathbb{N}}$, which is clearly bounded as it is the $k+1$-th component of a bounded sequence. By Bolzano-Weierstrass on $\mathbb{R}$, this has a convergent subsequence $\left\{x_{k+1}^{(m_{s_a})}\right\}_{a\in\mathbb{N}}$. Now recall that any subsequence of a convergent subsequence also converges. Thus

$$\left\{\left(x_1^{(m_{s_a})},\dots,x_{k}^{(m_{s_a})}\right)\right\}_{a\in\mathbb{N}}$$

also converges. But this means that all component sequences of

$$\left\{\left(x_1^{(m_{s_a})},\dots,x_{k+1}^{(m_{s_a})}\right)\right\}_{a\in\mathbb{N}}$$

converge, and so the subsequence itself converges. Thus

$$\left\{\left(x_1^{(m_{s_a})},\dots,x_{k+1}^{(m_{s_a})}\right)\right\}_{a\in\mathbb{N}}$$

is a convergent subsequence of

$$\left\{\left(x_1^{(m)},\dots,x_{k+1}^{(m)}\right)\right\}_{m\in\mathbb{N}},$$

and the result follows.

Comment: Thank you that's very clear!